# Django ModelForm - Multiple Forms in Template with Different Action Views and Redirects

Tags: python, django

Overall objective: be able to update and create records on multiple objects from the same webpage. And when the user updates or creates a record, they're directed back to the same page. When they're back on this page, the results of their post should be reflected and they should be able to safely refresh the page without resubmitting the form.

**Here is my views.py**

```
@login_required()
def index(request):
    activity_model_form = ActivityModelForm()
    rhi_model_form = RhiModelForm()
    activity_list = Activity.objects.all()
    rhi_list = Rhi.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = {
            'activity_list': activity_list,
            'rhi_list': rhi_list,
        }
        return render(request, 'ec/index.html', context)
    else:   
        context = {
            'activity_list': activity_list,
            'rhi_list': rhi_list,
            'activity_model_form': activity_model_form,
            'rhi_model_form': rhi_model_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'ec/index.html', context)

def add_activity(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        aForm = ActivityModelForm(request.POST)
        if aForm.is_valid():
            aForm.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ec:index'))

def add_rhi(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rForm = RhiModelForm(request.POST)
        if rForm.is_valid():
            newRhi = rForm.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('ec:index')
```

**forms.py**

```
class RhiModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rhi

class ActivityModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
```

**template (index.html)**

```
    {% for activity in activity_list %}
       {{activity}}
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    {% for rhi in rhi_list %}
        {{rhi}}
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <form aciton="{% url 'ec:add_rhi' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ rhi_model_form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="{% url 'ec:add_activity' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ activity_model_form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
           url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
           url(r'^forms/add_activity',views.add_activity, name='add_activity'),
           url(r'^forms/add_rhi',views.add_rhi,name='add_rhi'),
)
```

The page index.html is the main page that should hold several forms. In this case, I decided to go with model forms for all the built-in functionality they supply. Looking at other similar posts on here, it seems like creating different views to handle processing these forms is the preferred way to go. From there, I want to reload index.html but I want to requery the database to get the updated/newly created records.

Two problems:

1) The model view isn't saving. When trying to submit the rhi_model_form, I am redirected to index.html without a record saving. For what I've posted here, I did newRhi = rForm.save() but I have also tried just rForm.save() and saw no effect. Why do some examples have the save method being set to a variable? Why does that help? Anyway, it's not working in either case for me at the moment.

2) After submission, the index view is rendered but it goes through the if request.method == 'POST' portion of the code. Why does it do this? And if I refresh the page, it wants to resubmit the form. How do I get this page to load after submission with all the desired data and make it so refreshing doesn't cause resubmission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I was able to figure out how this code should be restructured. For other newbies who are trying to make it so users can submit different forms for different models on the same page and not be bothered with the pesky resubmit on page refresh, here is the general structure to follow:

1. Templates: put each model form in the template, but make sure the action attributes point to different views
2. URLConfs: have correct url-mapping in your urls.py for each view in your forms' action tags
3. Views: *create a total number of views equal to this equation: 1 + n. Where n = number of forms you want to process and the "1" refers to your actual page.* Create a separate view for each form you put in the template. In each of these "n" views use all the standard stuff you see in the docs (i.e. `request.method == 'post'` and `yourform.is_valid()` ). But the key is that, you need to use the `redirect('view:name')` after you process the form! I'm sure you could do `redirect('/view/name/')` if you just want to hardcode the view in there. Using this redirect function, the system does not pass any data back to the main page view that it calls (the "1" from above.)

**views.py**

```
@login_required()
def index(request):
    rhi_model_form = RhiModelForm()
    activity_model_form = ActivityModelForm()
    rhi_list = Rhi.objects.all()
    activity_list = Activity.objects.all()
    context = {
        'rhi_model_form': rhi_model_form,
        'rhi_list': rhi_list,
        'activity_model_form': activity_model_form,
        'activity_list': activity_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'ec/index.html', context)

@login_required()
def add_rhi(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rForm = RhiModelForm(request.POST)
        if rForm.is_valid():
            rForm.save()
            return redirect('ec:index')
        else:
            rhi_errors = rForm.errors
            rhi_model_form = RhiModelForm()
            context = {
                'rhi_errors': rhi_errors,
                'rhi_model_form': rhi_model_form,
            }
            return render(request, 'ec/index.html', context)

@login_required()
def add_activity(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        aForm = ActivityModelForm(request.POST)
        if aForm.is_valid():
            activity = aForm.save(commit=False)
            activity.lastModifiedBy = request.user
            activity.createdBy = request.user
            activity.save()
            return redirect('ec:index')
        else:
            activity_errors = aForm.errors
            activity_model_form = ActivityModelForm()
            context = {
                'activity_errors': activity_errors,
                'activity_model_form': activity_model_form,
            }
            return render(request, 'ec/index.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class RhiModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rhi
        exclude = ['slug']

class ActivityModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        exclude = ['createdBy','lastModifiedBy']
```

**template (in my case - index.html)**

```
    {% if rhi_model_form %}
    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>{% endif %}
    {% if rhi_errors %}{{ rhi_errors }} {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'ec:add_rhi' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
         {{ rhi_model_form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add RHI"/>
    </form>
    {% endif %}

    {% if activity_model_form %}
    {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>{% endif %}
    {% if activity_errors %}{{ activity_errors }} {% endif %}
    <form action="{% url 'ec:add_activity' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ activity_model_form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ activity_model_form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add Activity"/>
    </form>
    {% endif %}
```

Summary - the core concepts to keep in mind are:

- POST: do not use this method unless you want to change stuff on the server. Basically, don't have any code in any view that contains, checks for, etc "POST" unless if that view will itself process data from the user. In this example, that is why you do not see anything about "POST" in the index view.
- Redirect/Render: these two shortcuts are key. Redirect will send the flow of code to the view referenced in its parameter and it won't pass the context. In my case, that's exactly what I want. Render does not take a view as a parameter and should be used to "ship-out" data, in this case to the template.
- Side Notes: in the template, I wrap each form in "if" controls because I do not want to show a lone "submit" button for a different form to the end user if there is a form submission error on the current form being submitted. (Since a form's action calls a distinct view and since I reload the failed form if it didn't pass validation in its view.)